# Find the 1thext of the TD woth Jquery after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some trouble to get the text in a `<td>` and put it in an `<input>` Box
here you can find a small example.
The idea is when the user click the "Select" `<button>` it put the code from inside the `<td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Item.Custumer_code) <td/>` in the Input box with the Custumercode ID.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Entre a custumer code"
           id="Custumercode" 
           name="Custumercode"/>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Costumer Code</th>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Costumer Name</th>
            <th>Email </th>
            <th>Tel </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

@foreach (var Item in Model)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Custumer_code) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.custumer_name) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Email) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Tel) </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
                    Select
                </button>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
</table>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I create this:

**js**

```
$(".test").on("click", function(){
    var firstNotEmptyText;
    $(this).closest("tr").children().each(function(){
     if($(this).html() != ""){
       firstNotEmptyText = $(this).html();
       return false;
     }
});

console.log(firstNotEmptyText);

});
```

Finds the first td with a text inside.

here is a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6tJ6/25/)

Comment: Hello, Thx for your answer , this code will not work for me because i have more than 100 rows and each row has his own Button to select

Comment: Change it after your comment.